# Why is the Laplacian Matrix not symmetric?

Tags: r, matrix, igraph, symmetric

I came across the [why-laplacian-matrix-need-normalization-and-how-come-the-sqrt-of-degree-matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1113467/why-laplacian-matrix-need-normalization-and-how-come-the-sqrt-of-degree-matrix).

I have a weighted adjacency matrix `adjm` (file [data.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aOaiQNbzVAp1Ah45Gu1ftBjdfA2yj_db/view?usp=sharing) on Google Drive). The matrix `adjm` is non-symmetric. I have built the directed graph `graph` and then remove loops and multiple edges. The resulted graph is connected and simple.  I have used the `graph.laplacian()` function from the `igraph` package.  I expected to obtain the symmetric matrix, but the matrix `L_matrix` is not symmetric.

```
library(igraph)

# read from file    
adjm = as.matrix(read.csv("data.csv", sep=",", row.names = 1))

isSymmetric(adjm) # FALSE

graph <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(adjm, weighted=TRUE)

table(count_multiple(graph))

# remove loops and multiple edges
graph <- simplify(graph) 

is_connected(graph) # TRUE

L_matrix <- graph.laplacian(graph, norm=TRUE, 
                            weights = E(graph)$weight, 
                            sparse=FALSE)

isSymmetric(L_matrix) # FALSE
```

**Edit.** I tried to vary a tolerance `tol` from 0.1 to 0.0001 but the result is `FALSE`.

```
isSymmetric(L_matrix, tol = 0.01) # FALSE
```

The `L_matrix` is square `104` by `104` matrix. I found the difference between the first row and the first column. Then I calculated the number of zeros, it is less than `104`.

```
test0 <- L_matrix[1,] - L_matrix[,1]
test0 <- test0[test0 == 0]
length(test0[test0 == 0])
[1] 90
```

**Edit 2.**

I want to make a spectral clustering.

**Question.**
Why is the Laplacian Matrix not symmetric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"The resulted graph is connected and simple"* isn't right: the graph is still directed and the adjacency matrix is not symmetric. E.g.,

```
as_adjacency_matrix(graph)[1:5, 1:5]
# 5 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#      dddd dddD ddDd ddDD dDdd
# dddd    .    .    .    .    .
# dddD    .    .    .    .    .
# ddDd    .    .    .    .    .
# ddDD    .    .    .    .    .
# dDdd    .    1    .    .    .
```

So, as a result, the Laplacian isn't symmetric either.

**Edit:** as to make the graph undirected, we may use

```
adjm <- pmax(adjm, t(adjm))
all(adjm == t(adjm))
# [1] TRUE
```

In this way both elements (i,j) and (j,i) are replaced by the larger of the two. Interestingly, it still doesn't make the Laplacian symmetric:

```
L_matrix[1:5, 1:5]
#      dddd        dddD ddDd ddDD       dDdd
# dddd    1  0.00000000    0    0  0.0000000
# dddD    0  1.00000000    0    0 -0.0703125
# ddDd    0  0.00000000    1    0  0.0000000
# ddDD    0  0.00000000    0    1  0.0000000
# dDdd    0 -0.06575342    0    0  1.0000000
```

The issue is in how `normalized = TRUE` works (seems like a bug; at least it contradicts the documentation). Doing the normalization step manually we have

```
L_matrix <- graph.laplacian(graph, norm = FALSE, 
                            weights = E(graph)$weight,
                            sparse = FALSE)
L_matrix <- diag(1 / sqrt(diag(L_matrix))) %*% L_matrix %*% diag(1 / sqrt(diag(L_matrix)))
isSymmetric(L_matrix)
# [1] TRUE
L_matrix[1:5, 1:5]
#      [,1]        [,2] [,3] [,4]        [,5]
# [1,]    1  0.00000000    0    0  0.00000000
# [2,]    0  1.00000000    0    0 -0.06799476
# [3,]    0  0.00000000    1    0  0.00000000
# [4,]    0  0.00000000    0    1  0.00000000
# [5,]    0 -0.06799476    0    0  1.00000000
```

Comment: Is it exist a function in the igraph package to make a symmetric matrix?

Comment: It's not about existing, but about what you actually want to achieve. How do you want to symmetrize a matrix? Do you want for an undirected edge to exist if both directed ones are present? Or is just one enough?

Comment: I want to make a spectral clustering. I am looking for mutual k-nearest neighbors. But I think one edge is enough.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Why do you use the the command all(adjm == t(adjm)) instead of isSymmetric(adjm)? Because diagonal elements of adjm are not zeros?

Comment: @Nick, because `isSymmetric(adjm)` give `FALSE`, which clearly is wrong, and I didn't want to look for details why, but now I checked and see that `isSymmetric` for symmetry requires column names and row names to be the same as well. `adjm` doesn't satisfy that and returns `FALSE` just for this reason. After fixing row names it does return `TRUE` as well.